# Is it wrong to initialize a Firebase app in multiple components in polymer?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, polymer

I'm choosing to use the javascript instead of the polymerfire because is better documented, I ran the note-app but it didn't give me the full capabilities that I want to use in Firebase.

I'm using the code

```
var config = {
  apiKey: '<your-api-key>',
  authDomain: '<your-auth-domain>',
  databaseURL: '<your-database-url>',
  storageBucket: '<your-storage-bucket>'
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

in a auth component that's responsible to login the user, but I need to keep track of the auth status in other components that represents pages in my app. I don't know if there's a way to initialize the app globally or if repeating the app initialization in every page is the best choice. What I'm doing right now is initializing the app in the component's ready function of every page that can be initialized by the routing.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the polymer way would be to create a component that expose the application returned by `firebase.initializeApp`.

The hacky way I had to use in unit test on the server side is to try to get the app and if it fails, I initialize it:

```
var app;
try {
  app = firebase.app();
}
catch(e) {
  app = firebase.initializeApp(...);
}
```

Comment: I preferred the hacky way, it should be useful to create a component to work like an API of Firebase, but is unnecessary once that the javascript API already works and sounds silly to create a component just to encapsulate the firebase.initializeApp.

Comment: I agree with you, it's the part of the component approach I really don't like... In my Angular app and in node app I created a `Database` class that encapsulate the firebase app instance and expose only one instance of `Database` throw a singleton (and also add some handy functions on it)...

Answer (score 0):

If u are using typescript you can keep the auth inside class using singleton pattern. That way there is only one object shared across.

for javascript - use the js generated from the typescript file.

Comment: Why don't you give an example of the Singleton pattern here? Your answer would be more relevant... :)